# PCollection and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

We are looking into pcollection (http://code.google.com/p/pcollections/) to maintain internal state in our objects. The standard collection unmodifiable could work too but the being able to modify the collection without affecting the original one is attractive to us, especially when it doesn't come with the cost of a full copy.

The problem I have right now is that I can't find any evidence of Hibernate being able to support these collections.

So, the question, can we use pcollections with hibernate?